# c++ input line to vector

Tags: c++, vector, input

My target is to add input line to vector right after input(Enter hit). 
Example:

"1 2 3 4 5 6" - line input

to become vector holding that numbers

Code tried:

```
int arrLength = validateArrLength("Enter array length: ");
vector<int> arr;
int counter = 1;

cout << "Enter values:" << endl;
string in;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, in, ' ');

while (cin >> in && counter < arrLength){
    arr.push_back(atoi(in.c_str()));
    ++counter;
}
```

problem is that in while loop first value is ignored and it jumps to second. How can I handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have way simpler code like this:

```
int arrLength = validateArrLength("Enter array length: ");
vector<int> arr;

for(int val, i = 0;(cin >> val) && i < arrLength; ++i){
    arr.push_back(val);
}
```

Comment: When I type let say '34 45 51' it did not stop on enter

Comment: maybe loop from 1

Comment: @TeodorKolev Why are you asking about the number of entries then in 1st place?

Comment: @TeodorKolev If you want to consume an arbitrary number of entries you can ask the user to provide an empty line (just pressing ENTER without further input) to stop the input sequence.

Comment: I want when I enter 5 numbers and hit enter to move on. That code did not do that

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you avoid raw loop and use the standard library to do this instead. There are several constructs in it that come together in order to accomplish it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> arr;
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
            std::istream_iterator<int>(),
            back_inserter(arr));

  for(int i : arr)
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/9S6unc)</kbd>

`std::istream_iterator` is designed to handle input in the exact form you require (a space delimited line). It will detect the end of the stream more robustly as well.

The virtual "input range" created by `istream_iterator` is then  fed to the `std::copy` algorithm. That does the obvious and assigns each element in the range to iterator returned by `std::back_inserter`. This assignment is in essence just a wrapper for a call to `arr.push_back`.

---

If you really want to copy only up to a point, the standard library doesn't have a `copy_until` algorithm. But it's not hard to roll out our own:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename InputIt, typename ForwardIt, typename UnaryPred>
void copy_until(InputIt start, InputIt end, ForwardIt d_first, UnaryPred p) {
    while(start != end && p(*start))
      *d_first++ = *start++;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> arr;
  int count = 0;
  copy_until(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
             std::istream_iterator<int>(),
             back_inserter(arr), [&](int) {
               return ++count < 3;
             });

  for(int i : arr)
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/6tf73t)</kbd>

Comment: it did not stop on enter hit

Comment: No way to combine a couple STL constructs to make up `copy_until()`? I'm not sure but somehow rewriting `std::copy()` feels wrong to me.

Comment: @iksemyonov - You can hack your way out of it by throwing from inside the predicate of `copy_if`. That... feels wronger still to me.

Comment: That way, I see. I prefer not to throw at all, having grown up on Qt. But why wouldn't `std::copy_if()` work with a predicate without having to throw / abort? Must be a simple question but somehow I don't fully follow.

Comment: @iksemyonov - `std::copy_if` always traverses the entire range. The predicate is only for choosing what to copy, not whether or not to continue iteration. Which could work here, but it won't exit preemptively like the OP wants.